# Python use lxml with fileinput

Tags: python, file-io, lxml

Having a simple xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <child>abc</child>
</root>
```

I wanted to parse it from file and this works well:

```
with open('tst.xml') as test_xml:
    for _, element in lxml.etree.iterparse(test_xml, tag='child'):
        print element.text # prints abc as expected
```

However, I tried to modify script then to allow it parse xml either  from file or from `stdin` and did not succeed:

```
fi = fileinput.input('tst.xml')
for _, element in lxml.etree.iterparse(fi, tag='child'):
    print element.text

# File "iterparse.pxi", line 371, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97283)
# File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1411, in lxml.etree._encodeFilename (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:22515)
# TypeError: Argument must be string or unicode.
```

I'm not sure in what I'm doing wrong. Is the [FileInput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) object not a file-like object in python?

Comment: Maybe `lxml.etree.iterparse()` processes a real file only, and not any file-like object.

Comment: That is probably not true, because `sys.stdin` is said to be a file-like object and is parsed without any problem by `iterparse()`.

Comment: In Python 2.x, `sys.stdin` is by default a real file object -- by which I mean that its `type()` is `file`.  This is not the case for `fileinput.input()`.  Note that the latter has a method `fileno()`, but it returns -1.  I'm unsure what the point of having a method `fileno()` that returns -1 is, because any C code trying to use the file-like object by querying its file descriptor will get an error trying to use -1...

Answer (score 2):

Without deep investigation, it seems that the reason of an exception is that `FileInput` class does not provide `read` method.
To achieve my goal, I ended up writing my own wrapper for now:

```
class FileInput(object):
    def __init__(self, filename=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file = open(filename, *args, **kwargs) if filename and filename != "-" else sys.stdin

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.file is not sys.stdin:
            self.file.close()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.file, name)
```

I'll be waiting for a better answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to use the `fileinput` module, but directly do it like that:

```
if filename == '-':   # or, if we don't have a filename argument
    f = sys.stdin
else:
    f = open(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: But.. why? Your approach does not provide correct closing handling. I would have to write boilerplate `if f is not sys.stdin: f.close()` and it is not exception-safe in addition.

Comment: Your use of `fileinput` does not provide correct closing handling either...  In fact `fileinput` is a very old Python module, so it cannot be combined with the `with` statement.  How about using a `try:finally:`?  I agree it's a few lines of boilerplate, but I don't know of any more compact solution, sorry.

Comment: I simplified my example as much as possible, it looked like `with contextlib.closing(fileinput.input(args.input)) as input:` in real world, which provides necessary exception-safety, and works correct, because `FileInput`'s `close()` method has a check for `sys.stdin` and does not close it. Anyway, thanks for your help.